# Python problem - 2.7 vs 3.5 confusion with apt

Tags: 16.04, apt, python

Once upon a time I made a huge error and changed my default python to 3.5. I have since changed it back, however when I try to install or upgrade packages using apt, somehow python 3 is used and it causes some installation scripts to crash because of syntax errors.

Launching python:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
```

However, when upgrading packages:

```
Setting up playonlinux (4.2.10-2ubuntu0.1) ...
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib/playonlinux.py", line 306
    print "Deprecated !"
                       ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Is there a way to fix it?

EDIT:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python

myuser@myhost:~$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Comment: Include the output of `type -a python` and `/usr/bin/python --version`, please.

Comment: And of `/usr/bin/python2 --version` and `/usr/bin/python2.7 --version` as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the cause - `/usr/bin/pycompile` and `/usr/bin/pyclean` were still symlinked to the 3.5 versions of the scripts. Linking them to `/usr/bin/py2compile` and `/usr/bin/py2clean` respectively solved the issue.